# NULLS LAST flag in Denodo, MemSQL, Spark, VectorWise, and XtremeData

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore, vectorwise, denodo

I am doing a pseudo-ORM for a personal project, and I'm compiling a list of compatibility checks for the 20+ different SQL dialects out there.

Currently, I am doing research on whether a dialect supports the `NULLS LAST` flag, i.e. when sorting a table, have null come out as the last item like `1, 2, 3, 4, null` instead of `null, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

I have results for languages like DashDB/MySQL/MSSQL, etc (yes - they offer `NULL LAST`) however, the following dialects, I was unable to find the null-last-ability:

1. Denodo
2. MemSQL
3. Spark
4. VectorWise
5. XtremeData

A simple "yes" or "no" will suffice in your answer, however, if you could also write the query down on how to perform the `NULL LAST` operation, that would be great too!

Answer (score 2):

I checked on MemSQL and afaik the `NULLS LAST` syntax is not supported.  That said, you can achieve this by doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY IFNULL(bar, MAGIC_VALUE) ASC
```

Change MAGIC_VALUE so it sorts last/first depending on the data in the column.  If you are ok with a perf hit, you can mutate the value such that if its not null the value always starts with a prefix that sorts high, and if it is null the value sorts lower than the prefix.

Same thing can be used to implement NULL FIRST.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the other four dialects whether that can work?

Comment: Should work for Spark, don't know about the other ones.